# R can't find missing / blank rows in a char column

Tags: r, data-cleaning, na, blank-line

There is a char format column in my dataset named **start_station_name** with some missing values, so I'm trying to remove all rows having a blank / NA value.

However I know that there are more than 7000 rows with no value for the column start_station_name,
when I try to remove blank rows, R can't find them and only removes 50 rows:

```
SD_cleaned <- drop_na(SD)
```

Here is a sample of the dataset:

| ride_id | bike_type | start_station_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 273C6C2B99EBAC32 | electric_bike |  |
| 7AB7965997435172 | electric_bike | Rush St & Superior St |
| D6C2BC6711446FB5 | electric_bike |  |
| C2433C9CF5941BBF | electric_bike | Rush St & Superior St |
| ... | ... | ... |

I've also tried wit **na.omit()** or **is.na()**, but I had the same result.

Thanks for any feedback ️

Comment: `NA` values are different from blanks `""`. Functions like `is.na`, `na.omit`, and `drop_na` handle `NA` values, not blanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  In R, an empty character string is not the same as `NA` or a character string that consists of any mumber of whitespace characters.  To help you solve the problem, we really need to see a sample of your data as produced by `dput()`.  That's the only way we can be sure *exactly* what sort of "missing" character values you are dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

`drop_na` only removes the `NA` rows.  If there are blanks (`""`) convert the blanks to `NA` before doing the `drop_na`

```
library(dplyr)
SD_cleaned <- SD %>%
   na_if("") %>%
   drop_na()
```

---

If there are spaces as well, use `trimws` on each of the columns before converting the blank to `NA`

```
SD_cleaned <- SD %>%
     mutate(across(where(is.character), trimws)) %>%
     na_if("") %>%
     drop_na()
```

Comment: I appreciate it. Just worked.